# SAS Apparent symbolic reference when there is a n ampersand in data

Tags: sas, proc-sql

This appears to be an old problem but I haven't seen an answer that fully addresses it. Totally possible I just missed it.

I'm consuming data that has a text field called fullDescription that contains a string like (made up but fits the pattern):
"00001234456 Wells Fargo DR FM AT&T PYMT 00987600"

I'm attempting to parse the data and dig out tidbits like "Wells Fargo" and "AT&T". However, when I manipulate "AT&T" SAS tries to read it as "AT" then the variable value for T. It stopped erroring (but still warns) when I instituted this line:

```
%LET description = %SYSFUNC(COMPRESS(%BQUOTE(&&fullDescription&row),'',P));
```

This, at least, returns "00001234456 Wells Fargo DR FM ATT PYMT 00987600" (missing ampersand) but still throws:

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference T not resolved
```

I haven't figured out a way to prevent the warning. Is there a way to leave the ampersand in but not treat it as a variable? If that's not possible, can I cleanse it once and not get the error?

Comment: "consuming data"? What is the source of the data? How did you put it into macro variables? Why did you put it into macro variables? Why aren't you just working with the text in datasets?

Comment: Q: What is the source of your data?  
A: SQL Server
Q: How did you put it into macro variables?  
A: PROC SQL, INTO statement. 
Q: Why did you put it into macro variables? 
A: I'm parsing the description into individual components. In the above example we may want to group all things that reference AT&T or all things that reference Wells Fargo but make sure we don't include City of Fargo.
Q: Why aren't you just working with the text in datasets?  
A: I'm creating a new dataset that contains only the tokenized version so we can analyze it based on word adjacency and frequency.

Comment: If you have the data in a dataset (a reference to an external database) and you want to generate a dataset then just use normal code.  Use data steps, or procs, to manipulate the data and then you will not have any issues with macro triggers.  If you need help post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just add `%nrstr()` function when define the macro variable `fullDescription`.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('fullDescription','%nrstr(00001234456 Wells Fargo DR FM AT&T PYMT 00987600)');
run;

%LET description = %SYSFUNC(COMPRESS(%bquote(&fullDescription),'',P));
%put &=description;
```

This makes no warning anymore.

Comment: I don't know why but this wasn't quite working for me. Based on [the documentation] (https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n0o0rjikrg6iezn1ltra79iamibr.htm) it seems correct. However, you did lead me to function that is working. %SUPERQ seems to have done the job I need. Thank you for helping me get there.

Comment: %BQUOTE() is not the right macro function.  It will attempt to resolve the reference to &T implied by the text `AT&T`.   %SUPERQ() is a more directly way to quote the entire value of a macro variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a macro variable that contains macro triggers like & or % that you do not want resolved use macro quoting.

%SUPERQ() is useful to retrieving the value of a macro variable and applying macro quoting to it.  Use %QSYSFUNC() instead of %SYSFUNC() to have the results return by the SAS function quoted.

Let's create some macro variables like in your problem.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('fulldescription1','AT&T');
run;
%let row=1;
```

Now let's try your call to the COMPRESS() function.

```
%LET description=%QSYSFUNC(COMPRESS(%SUPERQ(fullDescription&row),'',P));
```

Results:

```
274  data _null_;
275    call symputx('fulldescription1','AT&T');
276  run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


277  %let row=1;
278
279  %LET description=%QSYSFUNC(COMPRESS(%SUPERQ(fullDescription&row),'',P));
280
281  %put ROW=%superq(row);
ROW=1
282  %put FULLDESCRIPTION&row=%superq(fulldescription&row);
FULLDESCRIPTION1=AT&T
283  %Put DESCRIPTION=&description;
DESCRIPTION=ATT
```